# Final static variable initialized in static block using method that throws exception

Tags: java

Consider following part of code

```
private static class InnerClass
{
   private static final BufferedImage connectionImage; // line A
   private static final int width;
   // other not relevant fields
   static
   {
       try
       {
           connectionImage = ImageIo.read(...); // doeasn't really matter - any method that throws exception
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
           // handle
          connectionImage = null; // line B
       }
       if(connectionimage != null) // line C
       {
          width = connectionImage.getWidth();
       }
       else
       {
          width =0;
       }
   }
   // rest of the class definition
}
```

I this case I am getting "variable might already have been assigned" on line B, which can be true if I had more lines in `try{}`block and exception was caused after my variable has been initialized. When I remove word `final` from line A it compiles ok, but I am getting warnings later in `static {}` block when I am trying to assign imageWidth/height (also final static) using `connectionImage.getWidth()` (of course if its not null). The warning is "usage of non-final variable during initialization". If I decide to use `final` in line A and remove line B, I am getting "variable connectionImage might not have been initialized" on line C.

My question is: Is there a way to have static final variables initialized and usable in `static {}` block using functions that throws exception (or generally inside `try/catch`) or I should handle other way? (constructor)

NOTE (if relevant):
Yes, the name of this class is to tell you it is inner class. Also it is static because if it isn't I can't declare static fields inside.

I know how to write code which will do what I wan't, but I'd like to have this inner class because of my convenience and to separate some behaviors. I only wan't to know the static final, static block, try/catch situation. I couldn't find good exlpanation for this in google, I even Checked my old 'Thhinking in Java'...

Here is something similar [Java - Can final variables be initialized in static initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339932/java-can-final-variables-be-initialized-in-static-initialization-block) but author hadn't try to initialize variable in catch, also he is not using them in the static block after assignment so he is not getting "Usege of non-final..." warning later.

Comment: Related: [Final variable assignment with try/catch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13604111)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you should use a local variable:

```
BufferedImage localImage = null;
try
{
    localImage = ImageIo.read(...);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // No need to set a value, given that it's already going to be null.
    // You probably want to log though.
}
connectionImage = localImage;
```

Now you know for sure that your `connectionImage` variable will be assigned exactly once.

I would then use a conditional operator for `width`, which makes it clearer that there's exactly one assignment:

```
width = connectionImage != null ? connectionImage.getWidth() : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks - this additional variable looks so obvious now... :) Also, thanks for the hint with ternary operator, but when I have width, height and maybe something else based on connectionImage it will be 3x null check, so in this case it will be beter to have if/else or maybe it will be optimized by compiler somehow?

Comment: @Kuba: Do you *really* think this needs optimization? It's in a static initializer - it's going to execute once in your application's lifetime. How much time do you think an extra couple of null checks will take? Right the most readable code you can. (That might mean making one object to represent the combination of height, width and whatever else - in which case you could still just have a single nullity check...)