# static final variable initialization in java

Tags: java, oop

I have a doubt in static final variable.In the following program:

```
class StaticPuzzel2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    }
    final static int i;
    static {
            System.out.print ("\n\t"+ StaticPuzzel2.i);
            i = 11;
            System.out.print ("\n\t"+ StaticPuzzel2.i);
            System.out.print ("\n\t"+ i);
    }
}
```

Even though the final variable has not been initialized it is not throwing error. Why it is so?

Comment: `static` block to initialize `static` variables. Nothing wrong here to throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're wondering why it doesn't throw an error when you access it before setting it to `11`. The reason is, that the variable is actually initialized with the default value (zero), and changed at runtime just like any other variable.

When using a static initialization block, the `final` modifier only makes sure you are assigning a value to the variable only once. What it doesn't do, is making it non-existent before that has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `static` variable in `static` block. That's why.

Try this:
`final static int i = 0;`

From java specs :

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned immediately prior to the assignment

So it doesn't actually means that if should be initialized at declaration. But it means that it can only be assigned once and this assignment can be part of declaration or initializer blocks as in your case.
This is will give you error now.

You can check this answer for more details.
[Java - Can final variables be initialized in static initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339932/java-can-final-variables-be-initialized-in-static-initialization-block)

Comment: but the rule with final variable is they must be supplied some value while declaration. Please enlighten me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4 for more info

Answer (score 0):

Because it has been already initialized in static block. If you comment out that line it will give a compilation error.