# While applying inner join on SQLiteQueryBuilder class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Why below code is placed in a static block?

```
private static final SQLiteQueryBuilder sWeatherByLocationSettingQueryBuilder;

//static block:
static{
    sWeatherByLocationSettingQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    //This is an inner join which looks like
    //weather INNER JOIN location ON weather.location_id = location._id
    sWeatherByLocationSettingQueryBuilder.setTables(
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                    WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    " ON " + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOC_KEY +
                    " = " + WeatherContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID);
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Could you provide some context to your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java

Answer (score 0):

This is `static block` which is treated as `static constructor` in Java. It is basically used in classes where you want to do something once.

For example initializing `static` variable `sWeatherByLocationSettingQueryBuilder`. Without this static block you should initialize your static variables from outside of the class which usually is not suitable.

For more info you can also see this post: [Java - Can final variables be initialized in static initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339932/java-can-final-variables-be-initialized-in-static-initialization-block)